ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.extern.six'
I'm trying to pip install streamlit-wordcloud (here), but I get the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.extern.six'

My Python and pip versions are:
> python --version
Python 3.12.3

> pip --version
pip 24.1.1 from C:\Users\...\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)

I tried doing pip install --upgrade setuptools as suggested here but it doesn't work.
Before getting this error, I got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils', for which pip install setuptools worked.
